# Newsletter subscription vs Registration

Tags: asp.net, membership, registration, subscription, newsletter

I'd like to have an easy Newsletter subscription box on my site. The user types his email, clicks "Subscribe" and he is done. The problem is that the site has Registration too. How should I solve the registration when the user is subscribed? I do have his/her email address (from Newsletter subscribtion) but I don't know if it is his/her.

I don't want to force the users to Register if they want only to subscribe to the newsletter list.

Should I have 2 email lists for Newsletter subscribers and Registered users and then check duplex emails and send the newsletter only 1x?

Comment: How should I solve the registration when the user is subscribed?....what does it mean? this ques. is lil bit unclear

Comment: There is Newsletter subscribtion - the site user (visitor) enters email and clicks "Subscribe" button and then he gets once a week (or month etc.) a newsletter. The second thing is the Registration on the website when the user (visitor) becomes the USER/MEMBER and Logs In/Out - the user has an account. While the Newsletter subscriber does not need an account. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user signs up for a newsletter but is not a registered member of your website, but later on decides to register, you can do a DB check upon registering them to see if they are subscribed to any newsletters, and if they are, set a 'SubscribedToNewsletter' column to true.

Or, if a registered user decides to sign up for a newsletter, simply set the DB Column 'SubscribedToNewsletter' to true.

Answer (score 0):

If your email client allows groups of contacts you could make two separate groups of contacts. If one of the newsletter people decides to register, they're name should pop up from the newsletter contacts and you can just move it to the registered. Hopefully that should keep you from sending out duplicates each time.

Comment: I have changed the email tag to asp.net because there is no usage of email client - it's purely website based application. All these things should happen automatically not manually.